# How do i make php tag readable in a string?

Tags: php

I'm try to run php tag inside a string like so:

```
$str = '<h1><?php echo Hello World ?></h1>';
echo $str;
```

But it returns

```
<h1><!-- ?php echo Hello World ? --></h1>
```

I want an output similar to this code:

```
ob_start();
require ("../view/file_name.inc");
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Without Using:

> require

or

> include

Using:

```
file_get_contents('../view/file_name.inc');
```

without templating as well

let say :

file_name.inc has this:

```
<h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
<?php foreach($data as $d){ ?>
  <p><?php echo $d->desc ?><p>
<?php } ?>
```

The output something like:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>desc1</p>
<p>desc2</p>
```

Comment: you can try with $str = '<h1> echo Hello World </h1>';  -> Remove the php tag.

Comment: Firstly, please extract a minimal but complete example. Further, describe how exactly you run your code.

Comment: example... something like the way cakephp mvc using it's view class

Comment: This behavior is not reproducible in any vanilla PHP version from 5.2 to 7.2

Comment: What does `../view/file_name.inc` contain, just the string or the assignment and `echo` as well? If it is just the string, you could `eval()` it and capture the output buffer. Not really something that I would recommend though.

Comment: assignmnet and the ecoh more ....like a hole html and php tag case like mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `htmlentities` function of PHP to achieve your goal.

```
$str = '<h1><?php echo Hello World ?></h1>';

echo htmlentities($str);
```

It will output

```
<h1><?php echo Hello World ?></h1>
```

**EDIT**
Use `eval` to execute php script in string. try below code

```
$str = '<h1><?php echo "Hello World" ?></h1>';
eval('?>'.$str.'<?php;');
echo $str;
```

Comment: it works but i want output to be <h1>Hello World</h1> it must read the php tag.

Comment: how do i remove this <!-- ?php; -->

Answer (score 0):

this should be help you

```
$str = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
```

Comment: wise but that won't work in my favour if i'm using file_get_contents('../view/file_name.inc');

Comment: so what do you really want to do? i didnt get it